# Packages listed in install_requires ignored when installed with pip

Tags: python, setup.py, install-requires

It is was probably asked and answered somewhere, but I searched a lot and I didn't found where. Sorry if duplicated.

I have a project (https://github.com/PyFPGA/openflow) which depends on pyyaml:

```
setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=['pyyaml']
)
```

When installed with `pip3 install -e .` pyyaml is not installed. It can be verified with:

```
$ virtualenv venv1 --python=python3
$ venv1/bin/python3 -m pip install -e .

Obtaining file:///home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/venv1/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bzc9au74
         cwd: /home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import openflow
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/openflow/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from openflow.configure import ConfigureTools
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/openflow/configure.py", line 25, in <module>
        from yaml import safe_load, dump
    ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ram@ram-notebook2:~/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow$ 
ram@ram-notebook2:~/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow$ 
ram@ram-notebook2:~/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow$ venv1/bin/python3 -m pip install -e .
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Obtaining file:///home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/venv1/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-0r0b115b
         cwd: /home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import openflow
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/openflow/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from openflow.configure import ConfigureTools
      File "/home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow/openflow/configure.py", line 25, in <module>
        from yaml import safe_load, dump
    ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/ram/repos_ram/PyFPGA/openflow. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It fails in my computer (I know, python3.5 is deprecated), but also in GitHub actions (https://github.com/PyFPGA/openflow/pull/7/checks?check_run_id=2171303843) using `ubuntu-latest` (with Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9).

I don't want a workaround. I understand that `install_requires` is the method to specify mandatory dependencies. I am wrong?

Thanks in advance
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was not related to install_requires. To read the version of my project, I was importing the file which imports yaml (which is not yet installed). So, I avoided importing my library at setup.py.